# Monaco Editor React UI duplicates on reloading

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

Monaco Editor React UI duplicates on reloading.

Here is my code for it

```
                <DiffEditor
                    height='80vh'
                    className='simple-editor'
                    language={fileDataOriginal?.fileExtention || fileDataModified?.fileExtention}
                    original={fileDataOriginal.value}
                    modified={fileDataModified.value}
                    theme={isThemeLoaded ? 'Blackboard' : selectedTheme}
                    onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
                    loading={<Loading isLoading loadingType={SCALE_LOADER} />}
                    keepCurrentOriginalModel={isDisposed}
                    keepCurrentModifiedModel={isDisposed}
                    options={{
                        readOnly,
                        renderWhitespace: 'none',
                        ignoreTrimWhitespace: false,
                    }}
                />
```

There is another editor shown below original editor sometimes on reloading.

Tried disposing editor by `keepCurrentOriginalModel` and `keepCurrentModifiedModel` property but it didn't worked.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, can you replicate your issue on codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/dashboard